# MacOS でエラー The entity type ‘X’ requires a primary key to be defined

Tags: c#, macos, visual-studio, asp.net-core

### 問題

[公式チュートリアル](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/adding-model?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio-mac) 通りにサンプルアプリ（MvcMovie）を作成しており、
以下コマンド時に表題のエラーが表示されます。

```
dotnet-aspnet-codegenerator controller -name MoviesController -m Movie -dc MvcMovieContext --relativeFolderPath Controllers --useDefaultLayout --referenceScriptLibraries -sqlite
```

##### エラー詳細

```
Building project ...
Finding the generator 'controller'...
Running the generator 'controller'...
Generating a new DbContext class 'MvcMovieContext'
Attempting to compile the application in memory with the added DbContext.
Attempting to figure out the EntityFramework metadata for the model and DbContext: 'Movie'
The entity type 'Movie' requires a primary key to be defined. If you intended to use a keyless entity type, call 'HasNoKey' in 'OnModelCreating'. For more information on keyless entity types, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2141943. StackTrace:
```

### 試したこと①

**「Id」の上に`[Key]`をつけてからスキャフォールディングコマンド**
→解消されず、表題と同じエラーが表示される

そもそも「Id」がある場合、それをPrimaryKeyとして自動で判定する為、
「The entity type ‘X’ requires a primary key to be defined」
のエラーは出ないはずでは？

・Models/Movie.cs

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace MvcMovie.Models
{
    public class Movie
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Genre { get; set; }
        public decimal Price { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        public DateTime ReleaseDate { get; set; }
    }
}
```

### 試したこと②

**「OnModelCreating」で「HasNoKey」を呼び出してからスキャフォールディングコマンド**
→解消されず、表題と同じエラーが表示される

エラー内容には「OnModelCreating」で「HasNoKey」を呼び出しすべき。という記載がありますが、
呼び出すのは「MvcMovieContext」という認識で良いでしょうか？

しかし、「MvcMovieContext」はスキャフォールディング成功時に作成されるクラスであることが矛盾しています。

コントローラーフォルダの右クリックメニューからスキャフォールディングする場合も「使用するDBContext Class」が必須であることから、スキャフォールディングを実行する前に「MvcMovieContext」を作成する必要があるのではないかと考えています。
[image: 新しいスキャフォールディングの追加]

また参考にしたサイトもスキャフォールディングコマンドの前に「MvcMovieContext」を自作していました。
参考：[ASP.NET Core 5.0 MVCのチュートリアルを丁寧にやってみた②（モデルの追加とDBの作成）](https://hirahira.blog/asp-net-core5-mvc-tutorial-02/)
※他にも多くのサイトがContextクラスを自作しているのが見受けられました。

しかし、先に「MvcMovieContext」を作成したとしても問題は解決されず、
表題のエラーが表示されました。

・Data/MvcMovieContext

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using MvcMovie.Models;

namespace MvcMovie.Data
{
    public class MvcMovieContext : DbContext
    {
        public MvcMovieContext(DbContextOptions<MvcMovieContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }
        public DbSet<Movie> Movie { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<Movie().HasKey(m => new { m.Id });
        }
    }
}
```

### バージョン情報

dotnet —info

```
.NET SDK (global.json を反映):
 Version:   5.0.401
 Commit:    4bef5f3dbf

ランタイム環境:
 OS Name:     Mac OS X
 OS Version:  11.0
 OS Platform: Darwin
 RID:         osx.11.0-x64
 Base Path:   /usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/5.0.401/

Host (useful for support):
  Version: 5.0.10
  Commit:  e1825b4928

.NET SDKs installed:
  3.1.412 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk]
  3.1.413 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk]
  5.0.400 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk]
  5.0.401 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk]

.NET runtimes installed:
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.1.18 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.1.19 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 5.0.9 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 5.0.10 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.1.18 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.1.19 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 5.0.9 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 5.0.10 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
```

Comment: 公式チュートリアルというのはこれ https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/adding-model?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio ですよね？ チュートリアル通りにやってないじゃないですか。問題はそこでは？ チュートリアル通りにやれば、質問者さんの環境の問題とかがなければ、間違いなくできます。

Comment: htb様から共有頂いたコミュニティの見解としては「独自のタグ表記（【MacOS】のようなもの）は避けるべきだが、文章にするのは問題ない。」ということなので、そのように修正いたしました。WebSurfuer様がおっしゃる通り、Mac向けとWindows向けの情報とでは参考になるか否かが決まりますし、今回記載した内容は同じことをWindowsでやってもエラーにならない上に。Mac向けの情報が少ないのでMac向けの方に参考になるように、また、サイト内での検索ではタグ検索は可能ですが、Google等の検索結果でタイトルをみてわかるように、という意味合いがあり記載した次第であります。

Comment: 質問者様、ありがとうございます。コメント欄が荒れてしまい、失礼しました。

Comment: 皆さま、話をまとめてくださってありがとうございます。文面につきましては、オンラインの文面によるやりとりだとお互いの意図が通じにくくなりがちです。私も経験がありますが、意見のぶつかり合いがどうしても不親切に見えてしまうことがあります。改めてスタックオーバーフローの[行動規範](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/conduct)をご覧いただければなと思います。なお質問タイトルの編集は落ち着いたようなので、これらのコメントは暫くすると不要とみなされて削除されると思います。ご承知おきくださいませ。

Comment: 質問者さん、質問の「公式チュートリアル通りにサンプルアプリ（MvcMovie）を作成しており、・・・」の部分の公式チュートリアルのリンク先も直しておいてください⇒ https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/adding-model?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio-mac

Comment: @WebSurfer 確かに本文のリンクがおかしかったので、(代わりに) 提示してある URL に差し替えておきました。 / WaltRyusan さん、もし参照している URL と違っている場合には修正をお願いします。

Comment: ここは質問者ではない第三者が質問者の了解を得ることなく質問を書き換えることげできるようですが、それが許されるのが信じられないですね。

Comment: @WebSurfer さん、はい、このサイトはいわゆる掲示板形式の Q&A サイトのようなものではなく、どちらかというと Q&A の wiki のようなサイトになっています。そうすることでひとつの Q&A の寿命を長くし、なるべく将来的にも役に立つナレッジベースを維持できるようにしています。詳しくはヘルプセンターの[「自分の投稿を他の人が編集できるのはなぜですか?編集はどのように機能しますか？」](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/editing)をご覧ください。他にサイトの使い方について何か質問があれば [meta サイト](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/)をご利用くださいませ。

Answer (score 1):

Solved by the following method. Thanks!

・MvcMovie.Models

```
   {
        public class Movie
        {
            public int Id { get; set; }
            public string Title { get; set; }
            public string Genre { get; set; }
            [Column(TypeName = "decimal(5, 2)")] //Add
            public decimal Price { get; set; }
    
            [DataType(DataType.Date)]
            public DateTime ReleaseDate { get; set; }
        }
    }
```

Comment: それは質問の解決策とは違うと思います。ここ→ http://jameschambers.com/2019/06/No-Type-Was-Specified-for-the-Decimal-Column/  に書いてある話で、警告なので無視できます。

Comment: ややこしくて申し訳ないのですが、質問者は自分であり、上記の方法で解消しています。

Comment: WebSurfer様  どこの部分でチュートリアル通りでないと判断されたのでしょうか？ちなみに「試したこと」についてはチュートリアル通りにやってエラーが出てから行ったことです。